# How do I test for css where the width is less than 500px?

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I have the following css code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #globalnav-bag .ac-bag-flyout-container .ac-gn-bagview-button {
        width: 100%
    }
}
```

The property knows that the css code is applied until the width is 480.

However, as a way to reduce the window size in Chrome, the maximum width value is only available up to 500.

So, through developer tools, Dimensions is set to Responsive, and width is set to a value of 480 or less.

The way to check whether the css is applied or not is checked through Chrome's Coverage.

Currently, there are setting values for various sizes in the corresponding css file, and they are set in the following order.

- min-width: 834px
- max-width: 480px
- max-width: 640px
- max-width: 734px
- max-width: 833px
- max-width: 1068px
- min-width: 641px and max-width: 833px
- min-width: 834px and min-width: 834px
- min-width: 834px and max-width: 833px

Do the values written in css affect the order?

Comment: Test for CSS? Affect the order of what? Sorry, but I do not understand your question at all. Please edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: And please could you explain this statement: "as a way to reduce the window size in Chrome, the maximum width value is only available up to 500."

Comment: @BrettDonald What I want to do is download the html and css files from the homepage that someone has created and sort out the areas I want to use (ex nav, footer, etc.

At this point, there's a huge amount of code in the css. (of these, the code you actually use and the code that you don't use)

I want to get rid of all the unnecessary code here.

In order to remove this unnecessary code, we will test whether it is a CSS in use or not and try to erase it if it is not in use.

Comment: @AHaworth If you reduce the horizontal size of the Chrome window, it doesn't shrink below 500px. That's what it means. Don't you understand?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see the relevance of its not shrinking further. The way to test is to use Chrome's devtools inspect facility which lets you set whatever widths you want. Why is the 500px in Chrome something you are concerned about?

Comment: @AHaworth As I mentioned before, the purpose is to remove unused css code.

The css code also has max-width:480px.

However, the size of Chrome does not decrease to less than 500px, so the max-width:480px code will not always work without devTools.

So if I made it 480px or less using devTools
max-width: I think the 480px code should work, but it didn't work. 

I checked with Chrome's Coverage for operation.

If so, is it because of DevTools that it doesn't work
Or is it because of the properties of the various sizes in the css file mentioned above. This is what I'm curious about.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "mobile first" approach. For example:

```
.some-class {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen (min-width: 480px) {
  .some-class {
    max-width: 320px;
  }
}
```

And than you don't need @media only screen (max-width: 480px).

Also, what are you trying to achive with these?

(min-width: 834px and min-width: 834px) and (min-width: 834px and max-width: 833px)

This doesn't make sense to me.